# How to read multiple parquet tables?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I've the following folder structure:

```
.
└── raw
    ├── enwiki-20200401-pages-articles-multistream.xml
    ├── enwiki-20200401-pages-articles-multistream.xml.bz2
    ├── stg
    ├── wkp_header
    ├── wkp_link_external
    ├── wkp_link_wiki
    ├── wkp_page
    ├── wkp_page_simple
    ├── wkp_redirect
    ├── wkp_table
    ├── wkp_tag
    ├── wkp_template
    ├── wkp_template_param
    └── wkp_text
```

Under all these `wkp_*` there are `*.parquet` files located.

When I try to read the data in the following way:

```
val df = spark.read.parquet(
      List(
        "raw/wkp_text",
        "raw/wkp_page"): _*
    )
df.printSchema()
```

I only get schema for `wkp_page` printed.

Why is that? How can I check if all the data (from all tables passed) has been loaded? How to refer to `wkp_text` table?

Comment: spark.read.option("mergeSchema", "true").parquet(...)
All parquet files must have the same schema.

Comment: @NirHedvat, my `*.parquet` files have different schema, so it explains what I see. Please add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
spark.read.option("mergeSchema", "true").parquet(...)
```

Please notice that all read parquet files must have the same schema